# How can I create a closable div on top of a website with a transparent background?

Tags: php, html, css

I am looking to make a div that floats over the top of an exisiting website and I would like the website to have a black colour matte over the top with 20% opacity with the div at 100% opacity.

I am limited to using html and css only at this stage.

My current code is

```css
.popup {
 margin: 75px auto;
 padding: 20px;
 background: #fff;
 width: 500px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
  <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
      <h2><center>HEADER</center></h2>
      <div class="content">
        <p><center>CONTENT</center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would like to add a close icon for people to continue browsing the website if possible.

More importantly, I would like the opacity of the entire website to be dark with the box being completely white over the top.

What do I need to add?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated fiddle with pure css popup

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <h2>
      <center>HEADER</center>
    </h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        <center>CONTENT</center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vikas Jadhav , that's close to what I'm after. However I want the pop up to be visible straight away rather than be triggered by a hyperlink. What would I need to change to that code to ensure that?

Comment: You will need jquery or JavaScript for that.show pop-up on window load

Comment: I don't have the ability to have that unfortunately. The website was built by a developer who created a custom console etc and made the entire build with php and css only. I might have to run it past my client as a div on the homepage. Unfortunately with the current code I have it scrolls with the page and doesn't dim the background. She wouldn't mind if we couldn't close the window but it does need to be visible on loading.